# How to read the 動＿下一, ＿下二 pattern found in dictionaries?

Tags: abbreviations

There's a common abbreviation system in dictionaries and I'm wondering how they're read and used.

Here's [an example](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E8%A8%AA%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=02469600):
[image: dictionary abbreviations]

I'm guessing it has something to do with how to fill in the blanks in the example sentences, but hoping you can save me the detective work.

Comment: For future reference, all the explanatory notes for the dictionaries at Yahoo are online [here](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/guide/index.html).

Comment: Great, thank you. [Found it](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/guide/jj/jj8_4.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- 動 is 動詞, verb.
- ラ means the verb conjugates on the r-.
- 下一 (shimo ichi) and 下二 (shimo ni) are abbreviations for [下一段](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8B%E4%B8%80%E6%AE%B5%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8) (shimo ichidan "lower monograde") and [下二段](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8B%E4%BA%8C%E6%AE%B5%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8) (shimo nidan "lower bigrade"). These are verb conjugation types. There are other conjugation types: [四段](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%9B%9B%E6%AE%B5%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8) (yodan), [五段](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%94%E6%AE%B5%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8) (godan), [上一段](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8A%E4%B8%80%E6%AE%B5%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8) (kami ichidan), [上二段](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8A%E4%BA%8C%E6%AE%B5%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8) (kami nidan), [サ変](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%B5%E8%A1%8C%E5%A4%89%E6%A0%BC%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8) (sa-hen), カ変 (ka-hen), ナ変 (na-hen), and ラ変 (ra-hen).

Answer (score 4):

動 stands for 動詞, and means it is a verb. ラ means that the last consonant of the stem is "r" (belongs to ラ row), which does not have significance in modern account for this type of verbs. 下一 stands for 下一段活用, a terminology used in traditional grammar. In modern terms, it means the stem ends with "e". I.e., the stem is "otozure-". 下ニ stands for 下ニ段活用, a terminology in traditional grammar for classical Japanese.